# How do I write my code in a way that when my containers are deployed as Rancher workloads they can communicate?

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, rancher

I have been using Docker to containerise a simple PHP web app that connects to and uses a mySQL database to pull data from. It also includes phpmyadmin as a UI for the management of the database. I have managed to break it up on my local host using Docker into 3 containers, an Apache web server container, a mySQL container and a phpmyadmin container. I now need to deploy these containers onto Rancher in the form of workloads but I am struggling to understand how the workloads can communicate to each other.

In the Dockerfiles and php code I can reference the name of the relevant container in order to connect to it, for example the php pages can reference the name of the 'mydb' container in order to connect to it ($host=my-db-container-name) and pull data from the database as does the phpmyadmin Dockerfile in order to connect to the mySQL server (PMA_HOST=mydb). On Rancher/kubernetes however you cannot do this with workloads etc. Can anyone explain to me some way to change my code so that this can be possible?

I've included some of my code to try and paint a clearer picture of my issue.

**SQL Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest


ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword1234

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=MY_SQL_DATABASE

ENV MYSQL_USER=user

ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=password

EXPOSE 9906
```

**phpmyadmin Dockerfile**

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

ENV PMA_HOST=my-own-sql-container //(Here would be where the database container name is referenced.)

EXPOSE 8080
```

**Example php script pages that need to connect to mySQL container**

```
$host = 'my-own-sql-container'; //Should it reference something on Rancher like the hostname of an ingress?

// Database use name
$user = 'root';

//database user password
$pass = 'mypassword1234';

// database name
$mydatabase = 'MY_SQL_DATABASE';

// check the mysql connection status
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $mydatabase);

if($conn->error){
    echo "not connected".$conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have DNS based service discovery you can create *Service* objects in kubernetes that reference pods and can be used to connect to these Pods.

Documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/